# Renaming figure names to start with user specified number

Tags: overleaf

I have a poster document and I have a couple of figures and want to start my caption in them starting from a specific number (ex: Figure 8, Figure 9...and so on). But it seems it takes a default value and starts numbering from 1.

I even tried with

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
```

But it does not solve my problem. Is there any way in LaTex (Overleaf) to automate this or customize this?

[image: poster-images]

Comment: For example˙, after `\setcounter{figure}{5}` you will have *Fig. 6: caption text*. Similar for table `\setcounter{figure}{3}` you will have *Table 4: caption text*. For an example, please provide MWE.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in order to add an MWE to @Zarko's comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setcounter{figure}{8} %<---- If you want to start with number 'n', then put 'n-1' here.
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics{example-image-a}
      \caption{Look at this brilliant figure!}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, it is not. It will be brilliant, if image will show Mr. Duck. Quack!

Comment: I am afraid that `mwe` does not provide Mr. Duck, but I support your wish to introduc(k)e him.

Comment: Oh, MWE provide figure of duck, see my answer :-)

Comment: I was not able to find it... I will take care of this next time.

Answer (score 1):

Let me spel-out my comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setcounter{figure}{5} %<--- figure starts with num, 6

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
   \centering
      \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
      \caption{Look at this brilliant figure of Mr. Duck!}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]